# Fade Out not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I seem to be having a problem with the fade out function in jQuery. When the key Z is pressed a video fades in and starts playing, when the key X is pressed the video should fade away. Whats happening now is the fade in is working but when I press X the video does not fade out but only pauses. If someone can help me out it will be a massive help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#video').animate({
    volume: 0.0
  }, 500);
  $('.name').fadeTo(1000, 1);

  $(document).keypress(function(event) {

    var key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

    if (key == 122) {
      $('.name').fadeTo(1000, 0);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.video').fadeTo(1000, 1);
        $('#video').animate({
          volume: 100.0
        }, 1000);
        document.getElementById('video').play();
      }, 1500);
    } else if (key == 120) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      $('.video').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#video').animate({
        volume: 0.0
      }, 1000);
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('video').pause();
      }, 1000);
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Narrabundah College Fashion Show</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Media Video -->
  <div class="name">
    <h1>Tim's Film</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <video id="video" controls="true">
       <source src="media/video/media.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any live demo ?

Comment: its working fine as you want check this https://jsfiddle.net/xfp53thn/2/

Answer (score 0):

The volume range can only be between 0.0 and 1.0.

```
 $('#video').animate({volume: 1.0}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The volume property should be range in 0 to 1. change `$('#video').animate({volume: 100.0}, 1000)` to `$('#video').animate({volume: 1.0}, 1000)` and it will work correctly.